# creating, connecting signal to button in a loop

Tags: c, linux, gtk

I'm trying to create buttons based on the number of lines in a file,
each button will print the line content
here's my code:

```
while (fgets(line, sizeof line, config) != NULL)
{
  GtkWidget *button = gtk_button_new_with_label (line+12);
  gtk_signal_connect_object (GTK_OBJECT (button), "clicked",GTK_SIGNAL_FUNC (type),line);
  gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (container), button);
  gtk_widget_show_all (container);
}

void type(char *string)
{
  printf("the line contents are %s\n",string);
}
```

all I get is
the line contents are

I suspect this is because I am connecting the signal with different arguments to the same button(button name does not change :()

I need to keep this dynamic, the file content changes alot, I neeed to create buttons based on the number of lines, and use those buttons to perform a function on the corresponding line.

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your hypothesis is partially correct. The format of a signal handler is

```
return-type function-name(Type *sender, extra arguments, gpointer user_data)
```

where `sender` is the first argument to `g_signal_connect()` and `user_data` is the last argument to `g_signal_connect()`. In the case of `GtkButton::clicked`, there are no extra arguments and the return type is `void`, so your signal function should have the following signature:

```
void type(GtkButton *b, gpointer data)
```

and you can cast `data` to a `char *` to print it.

---

That being said, your program will never work as written. When you pass `line` to `g_signal_connect()`, you are giving *each* connection the *same* `line` pointer, which will always point to the same buffer. So every time you `fgets()`, the line that used to be in `line` gets replaced. Assuming `line` does not go out of scope when your signal handlers do run, you'll just get the last line for every button. If `line` *does* go out of scope, **the behavior is undefined**.

The correct thing to do is to give the signal handlers a *copy* of the lines. You can do this with `g_strdup()`. Keep in mind that you are responsible for freeing these copies.

Comment: yup, I amended my signal connecting to be as such:           gtk_signal_connect_object (GTK_OBJECT (button), "clicked",GTK_SIGNAL_FUNC (type),g_strdup(p4));

I'm assuming since I'm not storing in a variable, this would not cause any memory issues right?

Comment: As I mentioned, if you use `g_strdup()`, you are responsible for freeing the memory yourself.

Comment: how can I do this in my case? would you help me out with this?